# Prevent specific css and js file from being cached htacesss

Tags: apache, .htaccess, config

How can i use the htacess from caching my main.css and main.js file. However i use multiple js files and css files like so

css --- main.css   dafault.css   new.css

js ---  main.js    acc.jss       new.js

what i want to do is prevent the caching of only main.css and main.js how can i do that but the rest of the css files as well as the js files should be cached

Answer (score 1):

Make the script & css references versioned. add a date time string at the end of file extension with ? mark.
Ex:

```
<script src = "main.js?ver=" + dateTimeNow />
```

Comment: I didn't get this thing with a variable to work like you put it above, but I used this concept of putting the version on the end using a ? so that worked for me.